# Token não valida requisição

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth

Estou seguindo um curso de spring que possivelmente esta um pouco desatualizado.
Mas vou me adaptando.
Acontece que agora, estou com um problema que não consigo resolver/entender.
Faço uma requisição de token, recebo o token, mas quando faço a requisição com o token que recebi me retona não autorizado.

Seguem as imagens:
Aqui o token
[[image: O token]
<sup>Clique na imagem para visualiza-la em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaG4u.png)

Tentei passar no header:

[[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sup>Clique na imagem para visualiza-la em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK6tH.png)

Tentei também passar o token via authorization:

[[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sup>Clique na imagem para visualiza-la em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVxRa.png)

Aqui seguem minhas classes:

```
package com.example.algamoney.api.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.factory.PasswordEncoderFactories;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("admin").password(encoder.encode("admin")).roles("ROLES");
        
    }
    
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/categoria/*").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic().and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .csrf().disable();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    
}


package com.example.algamoney.api.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.factory.PasswordEncoderFactories;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("angular")
            .secret(encoder.encode("@ngul@r0"))
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(1800);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
        .tokenStore(tokenStore())
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }
    
}
```

Alguém saberia me ajudar?

Se precisar de mais informações posso passar Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro estava em duas anotações na classe `ResourceServerConfig`.

Ela teria que ter as anotações `@EnableWebSecurity` e
`@EnableResourceServer` ficando assim:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("admin").password(encoder.encode("admin")).roles("ROLES");
    
  }

  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/categoria/*").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .httpBasic().and()
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
    .csrf().disable();
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }
}
```